# Symplectic cohomology of $T^* \mathbb{CP}^2$

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry

I'm looking for an explanation for why the symplectic cohomology $SH^*(T^* \mathbb{CP}^2,\mathbb{Z})$ is 2-torsion (I heard this in passing; perhaps it's not even true!). By a clever argument that I learned from reading Seidel (and should be attributed to Viterbo), if $M$ is a Liouville domain containing a closed, exact Lagrangian $L$, then $SH^*(M,\mathbb{Z}/2) \neq 0$. If $L$ is spin, then this works over other coefficients as well. In particular, if $M = T^*L$ where $L$ is a closed smooth manifold, then the zero section is a closed, exact Lagrangian. So we can apply this to $L= \mathbb{CP}^2$ and conclude $SH^*(T^* \mathbb{CP}^2,\mathbb{Z}/2) \neq 0$.

On the other hand, note that $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is not spin so we aren't able to extend this nonvanishing to other coefficients. I believe this is the example which showed that $SH^*(T^*L,\mathbb{Z})$ is not isomorphic to $H^*(\Lambda L,\mathbb{Z})$ where $\Lambda L$ is the free loop space. Rather, we need a local system whose monodromy depends on the 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2(L)$ (at least when $L$ is simply connected).

In a monograph by Abouzaid on these topics, he mentions this example was studied by Seidel but the note is unpublished (and I can't seem to find it online). If someone can point me to it, that would also be great but maybe that's not possible.